# Change Search Index Location in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search, file-search

How to change the folder  (directory) to store search index data for windows 10?

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways to do that:

1) Using search index settings in control panel:

First search for control panel in windows search and in control panel search for indexing options.
[winows search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFrMR.png)--[control panel search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6YsS.png)

Second after opening indexing options click on advanced and then select new. After that you give it the new address to store the location. [index settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVfLd.png)

2) Using registry editor:

First search for regedit in window search and click on registry editor.

Second go to this address: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search and double click on DataDirectory.

Third change it to the place you want but make sure to add \Search\Data\ at the end of the address. [registry editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgO2m.png)